# Указание width, height в процентах

Tags: css

Подскажите пожалуйста, нужна ваша точка зрения.
Адекватный ли тон на css верстке если вся ширина и высота указана в процентах?

Comment: ну, с шириной, допустим, нет проблем. а высоту Вы в процентах от чего указываете?

Comment: @humster_spb высота так же как и ширина, от расширения экрана.

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин тогда это будут не проценты, а vh

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин, с высотой так не работает - Вы бы хоть попробовали сначала

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё зависит от того, какую вёрстку Вы используете.

Виды верстки:

**Статический (Static)** - использует заданный размер страницы и не изменяется в зависимости от ширины браузера.

**Жидкий, резиновый (Liquid, Fluid)** - использует в CSS-стилях относительные единицы измерения вместо фиксированных. Обычно в «жидких» макетах шаблона используются проценты вместо пикселей.

**Адаптивный (Adaptive)** - страницы использует CSS медиа-запросы, чтобы определить ширину браузера и соответствующим образом изменить макет страницы.

**Отзывчивый (Responsive)** - для построения шаблона страницы используются как относительные единицы измерения, так и медиа-запросы CSS. Что подразумевает под собой использование преимуществ и «жидкого», и адаптивного макета.